# ReactJS increment counter becoming jumpy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval

this is a snippet of the react component. It increases to a point then it gets jumpy with random increment.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CountUp(){

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    function addCount(){
        setInterval(
            () => 
                // console.log(count) 
                setCount(count + 1) , 1000)
    }

    addCount()

    return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h4 className="time-text">{count}</h4>
                </center>
            </div>
    )
}


export default CountUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setCount((count) => count + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h4 className="time-text">{count}</h4>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hvfglp?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

It's because, addCount() is called every rerendering. And `setInterval` timer is created every rerendering. So if rerendered 10 times, then it will be 10 timers and `setCount()` is called 10 times at a time.

Please try like this

```
function CountUp(){
    const [initial, setInitial] = useState(true);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const addCount = useCallback(() => {
        setInterval(
            () => 
                // console.log(count) 
                setCount(old => old + 1) , 1000)
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (initial) {
            setInitial(false);
            addCount();
        }
    }, [initial, addCount])

    return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h4 className="time-text">{count}</h4>
                </center>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Should probably also clear the interval at some point.

Comment: Yeah, that's right